Wayland Autostart that worked formerly no longer does
A while ago I had used the following instructions set to auto launch Chromium in kiosk mode at launch and it has been working fine for several months, but now when I power on my pi chromium opens in shrunken mode and stays closed.
Does anyone have an idea why this might be?
Picture of autostart in my .config/wayfire file included below.
EDIT: I realize the bash file from the linked tutorial is commented out, but it worked previously without that step.


please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead ... format as code for readability

sorry... a bit new here. I will reformat my post.
